# GenericFacesPortlet No Display

Tags: java, jsf-2, liferay, portlet

I have a simple portlet which extends GenericFacesPortlet, e.g.,

```
@ManagedBean(name = "create")
@SessionScoped
public class ReleaseCreation extends GenericFacesPortlet {
    public void doView(...) throws... {
        logger.info("doView")
    }

    public void render(...) throws... {
        logger...
    }

    public void processAction(...) throws... {}

    //additional methods...
}
```

In my portlet.xml is:

```
<portlet-class>[complete_package].ReleaseCreation</portlet-class>
```

I'm doing this so on processAction or render I can get/set session attributes.  The problem I'm having is that when my portlet loads the contents of my xhtml never displays, but I can see the logged output in the console from render and doView.  I've tried invoking super within render in hopes of displaying the page content, but nothing...  If I remove the extension of GenericFacesPortlet and revert the portlet-class (in portlet.xml) back to

```
javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet
```

The portlet renders and functions properly, but I have no access to RenderRequest, RenderResponse, etc...

Can someone shed some light?  I'm using Liferay 6.2-ce-ga2 w/ liferay-faces-bridge 3.2.4 and Icefaces 3.3.0, if that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a similar [post](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14101547/viewscoped-managed-beans-and-portlets/14103828#14103828/) which helped answer my question. Once I separated the managed bean from the portlet implementation things started working well.